# Fortify: Null Dereference

Tags: c#, static-analysis, fortify

When scanning a C# project with Fortify, one of the findings is:

> The method ValidateSchema() in Helper.cs can dereference a null-pointer on line 95, thereby raising a NullException.

I fail to understand how this can happen, when I am explicitly checking for `xml` not to be null in line 93. The first argument of `Validate()` is optional according to https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmldocument.validate?view=net-5.0 .

Here is the analysis of Fortify:

```
Analysis Trace
Helper.cs:93 - Branch taken: (xml != null)
Helper.cs:95 - null : is declared and/or assigned to null value
Helper.cs:95 - null.Validate() : is not checked for null value before being dereferenced
```

The code looks like this:

```
 84:        public static bool ValidateSchema(string xmlPath, string xsdPath)
 85:        {
 86:            XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
 87:            xml.Load(xmlPath);
 88:
 89:            xml.Schemas.Add(null, xsdPath);
 90:
 91:            try
 92:            {
 93:                if (xml != null)
 94:                {
 95:                    xml.Validate(null);
 96:                }
 97:                else
 98:                {
 99:                    return false;
100:                }
101:            }
102:            catch
103:            {
104:                return false;
105:            }
106:
107:            return true;
108:        }
109:    }
```

Comment: Seems like a bug in Fortify - maybe passing `null` to `Validate` is confusing it?

Comment: I don't think that the argument is the cause for trouble here, as the last line in the trace suggests that `xml` is null.